# construct obect property using deconstruct on other object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can I build object on the fly using deconsturct? 
Like I `token` is under `this.request.body.token`, 
how can I get the value and assign it to a object property? Tried below example it won't work:

```
const params = {
    token
} = this.request.body

console.log(params.token) //undefined
```

I have to do this

```
const reqBody = this.request.body

const params = {
  token: reqBody.token
}

console.log(params.token) //123
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES2015 deconstructing into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157549/es2015-deconstructing-into-an-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a colon while destructuring to assign to a standalone variable with a different name than the property name:

```js
const obj = { request: { body: { token: 'abc' } } };
// obj is equivalent to the `this` in your code

const { request: { body: reqBody } } = obj;
console.log(reqBody);
```

If you're OK with the variable name being just `body`, then it's even easier:

```js
const obj = { request: { body: { token: 'abc' } } };
// obj is equivalent to the `this` in your code

const { request: { body } } = obj;
console.log(body);
```

Comment: I think I'll just stick to my old way this is so unreadable, btw thanks for the answer!

Comment: Learning the new concise syntax is a *good* thing - don't be afraid of using it, it has its place.

Comment: Neither are arrow functions, the first time you come across them, nor are `for` loops, nor are many other syntax constructs, but don't let that stop you from learning them - they're useful, and once you know them, you'll use them whenever appropriate, and be happier as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If the object you are destructuring has a few standard properties, you can do this by omission using [object rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring):

```js
const thisRequestBody = {
  a: 'a', 
  b: 'b',
  token: 'token'
}

const { a, b, ...params } = thisRequestBody;

console.log(params);
```

Comment: this.request.body is the params send by the frontend, don't think should spread it

Comment: It's rest and not spread, and it creates an object from all the properties you haven't explicitly destructured.

Comment: why not just `const { ...params } = thisRequestBody`?

Comment: Because then `params` would include the properties you don't need (`a` and `b` in the example).